# Transmitting small amounts of information using WiFi SSIDs?

Tags: android, location, wifi

Is it possible to allow 2 Android devices to communicate by using SSIDs? One device would broadcast a message by creating a hotspot with the message as its SSID.  Nearby devices can read and interpret the message. I couldn't find anything in the Android documentation that allow this. Is it possible on Android devices and how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this call to create a hotspot:

```
private boolean setWifiApEnabled(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig, boolean enabled);
```

...

```
WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    netConfig.SSID = "\"SSID_NAME\"";
// more configs here.
```

And to scan wifis around something like:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
```

You can read the wifi info from there. Maybe you can identify the hotspot by MAC address.